# Moment.js with Vuejs

Tags: momentjs, vue.js

I try to print out date time using like the following in `vue-for`

```js
{{ moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') }}
```

but, it does not appear. It's just a blank. How I can try to use moment in vue?

Answer (score 294, accepted):

With your code, the `vue.js` is trying to access the `moment()` method from its scope.

Hence you should use a method like this:

```vuejs
methods: {
  moment: function () {
    return moment();
  }
},
```

If you want to pass a date to the `moment.js`, I suggest to use filters:

```vuejs
filters: {
  moment: function (date) {
    return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  }
}

<span>{{ date | moment }}</span>
```

[[demo]](https://jsfiddle.net/m7e2xcf0/1/)

Comment: if using es6, dont forget - import moment from 'moment';

Comment: Filters are disabled in Vue 2+. You should use a computed property instead. See my answer to this question.

Comment: For Vue v2 you can use global filter https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-filter

Comment: Quick clear answer that works in a component. Respect.

Comment: @PawełGościcki are you sure about filters not working in Vue2? because for me they do

Comment: with spread operator: `moment(...args) { return moment(...args); }`

Comment: Filters are being deprecated in Vue 3. I've been using this method for a while now and now working on replacing quite a bit of code in preparation for updating to Vue 3. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/filters.html#overview

Answer (score 187):

If your project is a single page application, (eg project created by `vue init webpack myproject`),
I found this way is most intuitive and simple:

In **main.js**

```js
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.prototype.moment = moment
```

Then in your template, simply use

```html
<span>{{moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}</span>
```

Comment: Should also work for other application types aside from SPAs.

Comment: I really like this method of using Moment. Thanks for sharing! I've just implemented it but with a small change as suggested in the docs, Vue.prototype.$moment = moment. https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html.

Comment: Simple but you can't have type recognition in VS code.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Laravel mix with Vue 2.6.12 in my Laravel app. Thanks @Geng Jiawen

Answer (score 40):

In your `package.json` in the `"dependencies"` section add moment:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "moment": "^2.15.2",
  ...
}
```

In the component where you would like to use moment, import it:

```js
<script>
import moment from 'moment'
...
```

And in the same component add a computed property:

```js
computed: {
  timestamp: function () {
    return moment(this.<model>.attributes['created-at']).format('YYYY-MM-DD [at] hh:mm')
  }
}
```

And then in the template of this component:

```html
<p>{{ timestamp }}</p>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if, instead of using a parameter-less function, you want to use a function like:

`date2day: function (date) {return moment(date).format('dddd')}`

You cannot use `computed`, and should use `methods` instead.

Answer (score 21):

I made it work with Vue 2.0 in single file component.

`npm install moment` in folder where you have vue installed

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="meta in order.meta">
    {{ getHumanDate(meta.value.date) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import moment from 'moment';
    export default {
         methods: {
            getHumanDate : function (date) {
                return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why method, why not computed?

Comment: For display purposes, I used method. Feel free to use computed property.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example using a 3rd party wrapper library for Vue called `vue-moment`.

In addition to binding Moment instance into Vue's root scope, this library includes `moment` and `duration` filters.

This example includes localization and is using ES6 module imports, an official standard, instead of NodeJS's CommonJS module system requires.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

import moment from 'moment';
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment';

// Load Locales ('en' comes loaded by default)
require('moment/locale/es');

// Choose Locale
moment.locale('es');

Vue.use(VueMoment, { moment });
```

Now you can use the Moment instance directly in your Vue templates without any additional markup:

```html
<small>Copyright {{ $moment().year() }}</small>
```

Or the filters:

```html
<span>{{ 3600000 | duration('humanize') }}</span>
<!-- "an hour" -->
<span>{{ [2, 'years'] | duration('add', 1, 'year') | duration('humanize') }}</span>
<!-- "3 years" -->
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by explaining how this answers OP's question.

Answer (score 8):

```js
// plugins/moment.js

import moment from 'moment';

moment.locale('ru');

export default function install (Vue) {
  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $moment: {
      get () {
        return moment;
      }
    }
  })
}

// main.js

import moment from './plugins/moment.js';
Vue.use(moment);

// use this.$moment in your components
```

Comment: Nice use of plugins to isolate moment-related stuff in a separate file. Works great!

Answer (score 6):

For moment.js at Vue 3

```
npm install moment --save
```

Then in any component

```
import moment from 'moment'

...

export default {
  created: function () {
    this.moment = moment;
  },

...

<div class="comment-line">
   {{moment(new Date()).format('DD.MM.YYYY [&nbsp;] HH:mm')}}
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `computed: { moment: () => moment }`. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Moment.js with Vue3 js

```
npm install moment --save   # npm
yarn add moment             # yarn
```

Main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import moment from 'moment'

const app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.$moment = moment

app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

Used moments in vue3 js component

```
{{ $moment(item.created_at).format("YYYY-MM-DD") }}  // 2021-07-03
```

Answer (score 1):

> vue-moment

very nice plugin for vue project and works very smoothly with the components and existing code.
Enjoy the moments...

```js
// in your main.js
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
// and use in component
{{'2019-10-03 14:02:22' | moment("calendar")}}
// or like this
{{created_at | moment("calendar")}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`global` members are not available by default in your `<template>`'s scope. But you can easily pass them on using `computed` properties.

```
computed: {
  moment: () => moment,
  console: () => console,
  window: () => window
}
```

Now you can use any of them in your template. i.e: `console.log(moment(), window)`.

Note this doesn't add any overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the solutions posted here and it seems to be more complex than my solution so I'm presenting this one, what I do is like this

**The thing you need:**

```js
import moment from 'moment';
...
data() {
  return {
    moment: moment, // This is the one line of code that you need
  }
}
```

So this is what it looks like

**HTML (Now this works):**

```html
<h1>{{moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}}</h1>
```

**JS:**

```js
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      moment: moment, // This is the one line of code that you need
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply import the moment module, then use a computed function to handle my moment() logic and return a value that's referenced in the template.

While I have not used this and thus can not speak on it's effectiveness, I did find https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment for an alternate consideration

Answer (score 0):

TESTED

```
import Vue from 'vue'
    
Vue.filter('formatYear', (value) => {
  if (!value) return ''
  return moment(value).format('YYYY')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the moment module:

```
npm i moment
```

In your vue component:

```
import moment from 'moment';
export default {
   data(){

   },
   methods:{
     moment(date){ return moment(date) }
   }
}
```

Inside the template:

```
<span>{{ moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') }}</span>
```